# Is it possible to rotate CanvasRenderingContext2D around Y-axis only using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was trying to find the way to rotate ctx around Y-axis only using Javascript not CSS.
My code is below.

```
  function renderFrame() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
    x = 0;

    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

    ctx1.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
    ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    let r, g, b;
    let bars = 118;

    for (let i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
      barHeight = dataArray[i] * 2.5;

      if (dataArray[i] > 210) {
        // pink
        r = 250;
        g = 0;
        b = 255;
      } else if (dataArray[i] > 200) {
        // yellow
        r = 250;
        g = 255;
        b = 0;
      } else if (dataArray[i] > 190) {
        // yellow/green
        r = 204;
        g = 255;
        b = 0;
      } else if (dataArray[i] > 180) {
        // blue/green
        r = 0;
        g = 219;
        b = 131;
      } else {
        // light blue
        r = 0;
        g = 199;
        b = 255;
      }

      ctx1.fillStyle = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
      ctx1.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
      ctx2.fillStyle = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
      ctx2.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

      x += barWidth + 10;
    }
  }
  renderFrame();
```

I want to rotate ctx around Y-axis not canvas.
Is there possible way? or do i have to use WebGL?
If you ask why i need this,
I want canvas and context to fit in the left screen of the image.
[image]
what could be the best way to make canvas to be fit in?
Oh, i'm using requestAnimationFrame to keep drawing something on context.
That's why I need to rotate the context, not only the canvas.

Comment: In that case CSS transforms could be a very valid solution, rAF doesn't have anything to do with it. Unfortunately canvas2d still doesn't support non affine transforms (there was a proposal by chrome team to add it, but not all engines had a path to make it, so it's been dropped). So if you really want to do it on the canvas you'd need either a webgl context, either to split every frame drawn in a lot of small strips and adjust their height and width based on the "distance". That may quickly become a lot of processing per frame, so please explain better why you think CSS won't do.

Comment: @Kaiido I thought CSS won't do because I use requestAnimationFrame. I've used this function to create audio visualizer. I tried CSS transforms to the canvas, and for some reason, the visualizer ( audio frequency bars ) didn't rotate, but only canvas that contains the visualizer rotated. Is there way to rotate content of the canvas that keeps changing using CSS?

Comment: If you rotate the canvas everything drawn in it should rotate. requestAnimationFrame has nothing to do with it.   If you have a case where you believe that's not happening then I would recommend asking a new question.

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem Thank you for your information, Is it vaild for the context of the canvas too? I checked that putting image on the canvas through css, and using transform worked, but for the Canvas Context, drawing something in real time and rotating the draw doesn't work. It just shrinks the width, and not rotates. I'll edit my question to put my code.